# how to change the border-radius of the circle in fabricJS

Tags: jquery, frontend, fabricjs, web-frontend

I want to change the `border-radius` of a circle when I scale the object (`if scaleX/scaleY>1`)...

**This is my circle object in fabricJS:**

```
function makeStation(left, top, stationID) {
    var c = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 2,
        fill: '#5afffa',
        stroke: '#666',
        selectable: true,
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        borderColor: 'black',
        cornerColor: 'black',

    });
    c.left1 = left;
    c.top1 = top;
    c.hasControls = c.hasBorders= true;

    c.stationID = stationID;
    c.stationName = stations[stationID].name;
    c.description = stations[stationID].desc;
    c.image = stations[stationID].image;

    return c;
}
```

How can I change the `border radius`?

Comment: The html elemets are made round/circular using the border radius property itself. So why would you need a border radius on a circle?

Comment: What do you mean by border radius? you mean you want a tinner border when you scale the object?

Comment: @AdityaParab  I want to change the circle a little. now the border radius is 50%.. .so want when I scale , it will be 10px...

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi i want a smaller border radius when I scale... now the border is 50%..I want it to be 45%...or 10px...

Comment: @Moran  - The property you are looking for is `border-width` not `border-radius`. Set `border-width:10px;` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't, I think the border is controlled by the `selectionLineWidth` of the Canvas:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#selectionLineWidth

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet to see if this is what are you looking for.
StrokeWidth stays costant while scaling.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({radius: 50, fill: 'red', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth:2}));

canvas.on("object:scaling", function(opt){
  var t = opt.target;
  
  t.strokeWidth = 2/Math.min(t.scaleX, t.scaleY);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```